# A question about interaction terms

Tags: regression

Suppose we have the following variables:

- *Height*, a continuous variable
- *Sport*, a dummy equal to 1 if the person did any sports when young;
- *Vitamins*, a dummy equal to 1 if the person took any extra vitamins when young.

We set up the following regression:

(1)   *Height* = **a** + **b**•*Sport* + **c**•*Vitamins* + **d**•*Sport*X*Vitamins* + e

…

Suppose instead we define two new variables:

- *SportOnly*, a dummy equal to 1 if the person did any sports but did not take any vitamins when young.
- *VitaminsOnly*, a dummy equal to 1 if the person did take vitamins but did not do any sports.

We set up the following regression:

*Height* = **ß1** + **ß2**•*SportOnly* + **ß3**•*VitaminsOnly* + **ß4**•*Sport*X*Vitamins* + ε          (2)

It turns out that coefficients **ß1**, **ß2** and **ß3** in regression (2) are respectively equal to **a**, **b** and **c** from regression (1).

Instead, **d** is not equal to **ß4**. However, it must be noted that **ß4** = **b** + **c** + **d**.

I have two questions:

1. considering equation (2), how can we interpret coefficients ß2, ß3 and ß4? That is, should ß4 be statistically different from zero, would that be sufficient to draw any conclusions, and of what sort?
2. Is there any theoretical or applied paper, whether about economics or health or anything, which treats variables in this way, so that I can get some literature references?

---

and thank you for your answer. I get your point, however at this stage what I am also interested in is whether turning a two-variable regression model with an interaction (case 1) into what basically is a three-variable linear regression (case 2) makes any sense or can provide any additional insight.

For instance, suppose that we run regression (1) and that the interaction is statistically not significant. Then we run regression (2) and we find that the coefficient associated to "both Sport and Vitamins" is significant (which is what happens on a real task I am currently working on). Which of the two regressions can better help me understand what is going on between Sport and Vitamins? The one where the interaction is insignificant, or the one where it is? It might be a silly question but I am getting confused. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Tim Thank you for your answer. I get your point, however at this stage what I am also interested in is whether turning a two-variable regression model with an interaction (case 1) into what basically is a three-variable linear regression (case 2) makes some sense.

For instance, suppose that we run regression (1) and that the interaction is statistically not significant. Then we run regression (2) and we find that the coefficient of "both Sport and Vitamins" is significant. Which of the two regressions can better help me understand what is going on between Sport and Vitamins?

Answer (score 11):

Your first model has three features: *Sports*, *Vitamins*, and *Sports AND Vitamins*. Your second model has different features: *Sports AND NOT Vitamins*, *Vitamins AND NOT Sport*, *Sport AND Vitamins*. You can easily build a table (say, in Excel) showing the logical relations between all the variables. This would help for interpreting the models and the relations between their parameters.

| Sports | Vitamins | Sports AND Vitamins | Sports and NOT Vitamins | Vitamins AND NOT Sport |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |
| FALSE | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | TRUE |
| TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | TRUE | FALSE |
| TRUE | TRUE | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE |

You don't need special literature for that. Interaction between binary variables means multiplying zeroes and ones, so it is the same as logical AND. The only thing you need is logic and arithmetic.